# How to secure mongolab data more effectively

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, heroku, express

I am using mongoDB in my project, due to the Project's need, I am saving lots of credential data in my database. I want to know, how secure their web server is ? i am using passportJS now for authentication. i did use registered user check at all routing.

for your information 
i use

- passportJS
- mongoose
- expressJS
- NodeJS
- Heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem basically boils down to the fact that bodyParser creates a temp file on your server for every request leaving you wide open to a DDOS attack. You can replace app.use(express.bodyParser()); with app.use(express.urlencoded());

Also, please go through http://expressjs.com/api.html  and 
http://wegnerdesign.com/blog/why-node-js-security/